# Route Mismatch Fraction (map-matching)

Tags: python, maps, openstreetmap, mapping, benchmarking

Is there a Python (or another language) implementation of a function that has as an input a map-matched trajectory and a ground-truth trajectory and calculates the Route Mismatch Fraction that is first mentioned in [Hidden Markov Map Matching Through Noise and Sparseness Paul Newson and John Krumm](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/map-matching-ACM-GIS-camera-ready.pdf).
[image]